# Does upgrading my ckeditor requires my JSF to be upgraded ? I am currently using JSF 1.2 which is older version

Tags: jsf, ckeditor, jsf-1.2

I am upgrading my CKEditor to latest release to resolve xss attacks vulnerability.

Do I need to upgrade my JSF framework version in any case ?

Comment: No, why? Did you try? Errors?

Comment: CKEditor is not a JSF component its a third library